# How can I efficiently extract unique elements from a list in Python?

Tags: python, list, set

I have a list in Python that may contain duplicate elements, and I want to extract only the unique elements from it. I tried using the set() function to convert the list to a set, as I know that sets automatically remove duplicates. However, when I convert the list to a set and then back to a list, the order of the elements changes.

Here's the code I used:

python
Copy code

```
my_list = [3, 2, 1, 2, 4, 3]
unique_list = list(set(my_list))
print(unique_list)
```

Expected Output:

```
[3, 2, 1, 4]
```

Actual Output:

```
[1, 2, 3, 4]
```

I expected the unique elements to be extracted while preserving the original order of the list. Is there a more efficient way to achieve this without altering the order of the elements? Thank you for your help!

Comment: *"Here's the code I used:"* you mean the code ChatGPT vomited to you?

Answer (score 3):

You can do:

```
my_list = [3, 2, 1, 2, 4, 3]
unique_list = list(dict.fromkeys(my_list))
# [3, 2, 1, 4]
```

This works because `dict` [maintains insertion order](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39980323/are-dictionaries-ordered-in-python-3-6) unlike `set`.
Docs:

- [`dict.fromkeys`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/stdtypes.html#dict.fromkeys)

Answer (score 0):

One more way:

```
from more_itertools import unique_everseen
my_list = [3, 2, 1, 2, 4, 3]
list(unique_everseen(my_list))

# [3, 2, 1, 4]
```